# Float comparison gives different results

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Look at the following two codes, and tell me the reason why answers vary a lot.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    float a = 0.9;
    if(a<0.9)
        printf("hi"); // This will be the answer
    else
        printf("bye");
    return 0;
}
```

And if we change 0.9 to 0.8, then else's statement is printed:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    float a = 0.8;
    if(a<0.8)
        printf("hi");
    else
        printf("bye");//this will be the answer
    return 0;
}
```

So why this output changes when we just change a single digit?

Comment: Don't be so dramatic! _just change a single digit_! You change a single digit in any program anywhere, the output changes.

Comment: Also, read my answer too. I made a mistake at first and got -1s, but then edited it and now it includes a common workaround to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know how floating points works.

Floating points are represented by using powers of two, each digit is used to represent `2^-x` where X is the n-th digit.

For example, `0.011` (binary) would be `2^-2 + 2^-3`, which is `0.25 + 0.125 = 0.375`

Now try to represent `0.9`. You are in trouble, since no power of two to represent it. The value this is represented in 32-bits and probably 64-bits machines will give a result slightly smaller than 0.9, <s>whereas for 0.8 the result is precise and representable by powers of two</s>.

You can try this out by opening a `python` prompt. Try and type a few numbers, eventually one will end with `...99999999`.

Comment: @wormsparty: `0.8` is not exactly representable in single or double precision float.

Comment: Both 0.8 and 0.9 when converted to binary are recurring.Than what is the difference that makes both of the conditions work differently.?

Comment: The problem is that 0.8 is put into a float, so it has some binary representation probably in 32-bits of a number close to 0.8f. Afterwards, the comparaison is made on a double, so to compare it, it casts the float to a double in 64-bits representation, which no longer represents 0.8 exactly, but some other really close number. It compares it to the double 0.8, which did not suffer from the conversion. Look at the answers below for more details.

Answer (score 10):

This error is due to floating point accuracy and because you are comparing a `float` type with a `double` value. Try to compare it versus floating point literals: `if(a<0.8f)`

I suggest you read the according [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), it explains in detail why your error happens.

Comment: @Constantinius: Yes, i am agree with your explanation ragarding asked question, but why not same thing is happening with #include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    float a = 0.9;
    if(a<0.9)
        printf("hi");
    else
        printf("bye");//this will be the answer
    return 0;
}
Acording to ur answer  bye shud be print, but it's not...But when change 0.9 to 0.8 it is ok..

Comment: @Nishant: Because for 0.9, the (inaccurate) single precision value happens to be less than the (inaccurate) double precision value whereas for 0.8 it is greater.

Answer (score 5):

The literals `0.9` and `0.8` have type `double`. Since both values cannot be represented exactly, they will in fact be `0.9000000000000000222...` and `0.8000000000000000444...`.

When stored in the `float` (single precision) variable `a` they will be converted to single and become even more inaccurate: `0.89999997...` and `0.8000000119...`.

For the comparison with the literal `double` value they are converted back to `double` retaining the more inaccurate value.

As you can see from the numbers above, the comparison yields different results for `0.9` and `0.8`.

All this is assuming your platform has IEEE754 floats which is most probably the case.

You can see single/double representations of numbers at [www.binaryconvert.com](http://www.binaryconvert.com/).

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard:

> 6.3.1.5 Real ﬂoating types
>
> 1) When a float is promoted to double or long double, or a double is
>   promoted to long double, its value is unchanged.
>
> 2) When a double is demoted to float, a long double is demoted to double
>   or float, or a value being represented in greater precision and range
>   than required by its semantic type (see 6.3.1.8) is explicitly
>   converted to its semantic type, if the value being converted can be
>   represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value
>   being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but
>   cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher
>   or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an
>   implementation-deﬁned manner. If the value being converted is outside
>   the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undeﬁned.

The standard can be found **[here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as others mentioned, use values like `0.8f` when working with `float`s.

Also, floating point `==` comparison is something you would want to avoid because of the precision of this operation in the FPU. What always worked best for me, was to define a margin, let's say `1e-6f` (or the precision you need based on your application) and instead of this:

```
if (LHS == RHS)
```

you write:

```
if (LHS-RHS < MARGIN && RHS-LHS < MARGIN)
```

You could write a function (if you are a c++ fan) or macro (if you are a c fan (here comes the -1s)) that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to rounding errors, to see the value of that you are using insert a printf before the if:

```
printf("a=%f\n", a);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Instead of "if(a<0.9)" compare using "if(a<0.9f)"