# Strange behavior when comparing float with a constant

Tags: c++

I was struck by this strange behavior:

```
float pi = 3.14;

if(pi == 3.14)
    cout << "OK";
else
    cout << "How is it possible?";
```

Could anyone explain this?

Comment: You forgot to describe the behavior, and what was strange about it.

Comment: Your `pi` is `3.1400001049041748046875` (13170115 * 2^-22), and you're comparing it with `3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875` (7070651414971679 * 2^-51). Of course they aren't equal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float comparison gives different results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580352/float-comparison-gives-different-results)

Comment: -1 No behaviour is described.

Comment: The short answer is that your `pi` is a `float`, but `3.14` is a `double`. Most numbers (that can't be represented precisely in binary) won't compare equal in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constant in the `if` statement is `(double)3.14`. It is very close to its `float` version, but not exactly equals it, because `3.14` is not represented exactly.

Try the same trick with `1.25` or any other number that can be represented exactly, and you will get an `OK`.

```
float num = 1.25;
if(num == 1.25)
    cout << "OK";
else
    cout << "How is it possible?";
```

You could also cast `3.14` to `float` to get an `OK`:

```
float pi = 3.14;

if(pi == (float)3.14)
    cout << "OK";
else
    cout << "How is it possible?";
```

Comment: Instead of `(float)3.14`, you can just write `3.14f` (the "f" indicates that it is a `float` and not a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Because by default values like `3.14` are treated as double, but storing one of this value in a float variable causes a loss of precision; and so there are microscopic differences related to the different precisions.
Here's why floating point numbers shouldn't be compared directly most of the time.